# Average response time by path in loki logs

Tags: logging, grafana, grafana-loki, logql

I have stream of http logs json via Loki that look like:

```
2022-11-30 16:18:46 {"message":{"duration":"8.37ms","env":"dev","path":"/rest/path1","status":200}} 
2022-11-30 16:18:46 {"message":{"duration":"112.32ms","env":"dev","path":"/rest/path2","status":200}}   
2022-11-30 16:18:46 {"message":{"duration":"32.37ms","env":"dev","path":"/rest/path1","status":200}} 
2022-11-30 16:18:46 {"message":{"duration":"21.337ms","env":"dev","path":"/rest/path3","status":200}}
```

I'd like to display average response time by path.

I am able convert this data in to table with grafana transformation.
and then looking to for average of max duration time based on path.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried looking at range queries?
First you would need to extract the duration. [See how I did it here using the LogQL Analyzer.](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/analyzer/?query=%7C%20pattern%20%60%3Cdate%3E%20%3Ctime%3E%20%3Cjson_content%3E%60%20%7C%20line_format%20%22%7B%7B.json_content%7D%7D%22%20%7C%20json&line%5B%5D=2022-11-30%2016%3A18%3A46%20%7B%22message%22%3A%7B%22duration%22%3A%228.37ms%22%2C%22env%22%3A%22dev%22%2C%22path%22%3A%22%2Frest%2Fpath1%22%2C%22status%22%3A200%7D%7D%20&line%5B%5D=2022-11-30%2016%3A18%3A46%20%7B%22message%22%3A%7B%22duration%22%3A%22112.32ms%22%2C%22env%22%3A%22dev%22%2C%22path%22%3A%22%2Frest%2Fpath2%22%2C%22status%22%3A200%7D%7D%20%20%20&line%5B%5D=2022-11-30%2016%3A18%3A46%20%7B%22message%22%3A%7B%22duration%22%3A%2232.37ms%22%2C%22env%22%3A%22dev%22%2C%22path%22%3A%22%2Frest%2Fpath1%22%2C%22status%22%3A200%7D%7D%20&line%5B%5D=2022-11-30%2016%3A18%3A46%20%7B%22message%22%3A%7B%22duration%22%3A%2221.337ms%22%2C%22env%22%3A%22dev%22%2C%22path%22%3A%22%2Frest%2Fpath3%22%2C%22status%22%3A200%7D%7D)

Then you can use a [range query](https://grafana.com/blog/2021/01/11/how-to-use-logql-range-aggregations-in-loki/) with `avg_over_time`.

You would end up with a query like this:

```
avg_over_time(
{app="your-app} 
| pattern `<date> <time> <json_content>` 
| line_format "{{.json_content}}" 
| json
| unwrap message_duration | __error__=""[1m]) 
by (message_path)
```

Hope this helps :).